# query to search related fields

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have the tables and i am trying to get the active name(s) of a product by using the tracking Id.

These are the tables i have:

```
tblactive:       tblProductcode:      tblproduct       tblCV
client_name      client_name          client_name      Tracking_id
Product_name     product_name         product_name     product_code
active_name      product_code         status
                                      color
```

I want to be able to search for the active name when i key in the tracking id:
I have been thinking about this for awhile but just cannot figure out... probably monday blues.

This is the sql query i have currently have:

```
SELECT tblActive.active_name, tblActive.l4
FROM (tblActive INNER JOIN tblProductCode ON 
(tblActive.Client_Name = tblProductCode.Client_Name) 
AND (tblActive.Product_Name = tblProductCode.Product_Name)) 
INNER JOIN tblCV ON tblProductCode.Product_Code = tblCV.Product_Code
WHERE (((tblcv.product_code)=[forms]![frmCVSwabRequest]![cboProduct_code]));
```

This query just returns a blank.

Comment: What's the bound column of your combobox on Form `frmCVSwabRequest`? If you do not use the `.Column()` method when referencing your combobox, you may be comparing `product_code` to an unexpected variable.

Comment: Your query's `WHERE` clause references the combo's `Value` property.  Check whether it is what you expect.  With the form open in Form View, go to the Immediate window (Ctrl+g will take you there), paste in the following highlighted text and press Enter.  `Debug.Print [forms]![frmCVSwabRequest]![cboProduct_code].Value`

Comment: after checking christopher's & hans reply and got empty results .... i went for a coffee break..... turns out that the code actually works perfectly fine... realize i was using a non-existing product code....

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just make a unique primary key named tblactive_id for table tblactive
and add it to the tblCV table. Then simply run this query,

> SELECT tblactive.active_name  FROM tblactive, tblCV WHERE
>   tblactive.tblactive_id = tblCV.tblactive;

I think you need to redesign your database tables properly.

Comment: i cannot do that as there are multiple actives that are present within a product code. Sorry for not explaining clearly on that matter. Each product  code is tied to the product table

Comment: than just add product_code into the tblactive table also. Why are you trying to make your life harder.

Comment: yes that would make my life way way easier but it would defeat the purpose of normalizing the data set